# Deploy SSIS Packages developed using SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

So I have a suite of SSIS packages that we created using Visual Studio 2008 and are currently deployed on a SQL Server 2008R2 instance.  However, I would like to upgrade these to 2012 via SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 which is easy enough, however, the company that I work for does not have any plans to upgrade the SQL Server to 2012 any time soon.  So is there a way to create SSIS packages using SSIS 2012 and deploy them to a SQL Server 2008R2 instance while maintaining all of the new features of the SSIS 2012 package.  IE Project Connection Managers and Package Parameters, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. The Integration Services Service, the engine that which makes the package go, would have to be installed on the machine to be able to interpret/run them. Furthermore, unless you planned on running the packages from their .ispac containers, you wouldn't be able to take advantage of the rest of the "goodies" like the Environments, at least not without writing some ugly exec calls.

Also, if you think about slipping the IS services on that box, it is my understanding that's a SQL Server license consumed and given the ugliness that is the new per core licensing model on 2012, I wouldn't be happy writing that cheque. Not saying *you'd* do that, just a headache I saw at a client site when the auditors stopped by.